# Least Square Solution to Linear Regression Problem

Tags: regression, least-squares, matrix, matrix-inverse

Given two column-vectors, `A = [0; 1.6818; 2.8284; 3.8337; 4.7568; 5.6234]` and `B = [0; 984.7; 1590.7; 2029.1; 2251.9; 2254.45]`, I need to find a *scalar x*, such that it satisfies the following condition:

$Ax = B$

Using Matrix calculation, it can be easily solved as follows:

$ \boldsymbol{A}x = \boldsymbol{B}\\
\implies x = \boldsymbol{A}^{-1}\boldsymbol{B} \\
\implies x = {(\boldsymbol{A^T}\boldsymbol{A})}^{-1}\boldsymbol{A^T}\boldsymbol{B} \\ \textrm{(Taking pseudo-inverse of A)}
$

Solving this gives `x = 467.8599`.

Which is correct, since I verified it in MATLAB using:

```
x = A\B
x = linsolve(A, B)
```

Now my question is, can I obtain the same result if I approach this problem as finding a least square solution of the regression **A**x = **B**. That is, can I obtain `x = 467.8599` by minimizing for `E` where,

$E = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{6}{{\{A_nx - B_n\}}^2}$

If yes, can you please explain how.

Also let me know if there is some mistake in my understanding. Thanks in advance.

Comment: read the Matlab documentation, the implementations you mention perform least squares on non-square matrices

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.
Yeah, it performs QR decomposition on non-square matrices (LU Factorization if square matrices).

Comment: Yes, you just did, tow different ways. Here's another: x = pinv(A)*B

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a minimum of $E$.

Therefore, just have to choose the value of $x$ such as the derivative of $E$ wrt $x$ is 0.